# Find two parameters so that a function is continuous at a given point

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let

$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
  3x      & x < 3 \\ 
  a       & x = 3 \\ 
  x^2 + b & x > 3
\end{cases}
$$

Find $a, b$ so that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=3$, then prove that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=3$.

Guys, any explanation is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)$ is continuous at $x=3$ if and only if 
$\lim_{x\rightarrow3^{-}}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow3^{+}}f(x)=f(3)$, i.e. 
$\lim_{x\rightarrow3^{-}}3x=\lim_{x\rightarrow3^{+}}x^{2}+b=a$, so $9=9+b=a$, it means that $a=9$ and $b=0$.

Comment: how did you get to define a=9

Comment: @carolina nunez: I think it's obvious. Just observed and be more careful.

Answer (score 0):

The critical point is $x=3$. At this point you want $a = 3x = x^2 + b$ for $f$ to be continuous.

If you draw it, say for $x \in [0,5]$, you will immediately see which value $a = f(3)$ has to be in order for $f$ to be continuous. You really want to draw a picture.

Hope this helps.

Comment: why is a= 3x if it says the function is a if x=3

Comment: @carolinanunez First your function is $3x$ then it is $a$ and then it is $x^2 + b$. It is $a$ where $x$ is $3$. For it to be continuous you want $3x = a = x^2 + b$ (try to draw the function for $x \in [0,5]$)

Comment: @carolinanunez When you draw it you will immediately see which value you want $a = f(3)$ to be so that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: ugh, i feel like my prof is doing a poor job. I dont even know how to graph it.